# Can I send some large data over GCM?

Tags: android, transfer, google-cloud-messaging

My team is on developing to android app.

we want send some file to client on GCM

I knew GCM can send 4kb of payload, and it can send 1000EA's message for onetime.

so.. Can we send just 4mb data of file for onetime?

please help us!

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend uploading the file elsewhere, and putting a URL to the file in the content of the GCM message that would tell the receiver to download from the URL.

A message with contents over 4KB cannot be sent. Plus, they could be received out of order anyways.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want to use GCM for this. Unless the file is under 4kb, it's best to look into a better way of sending the file to the client rather than chunking it in GCM messages. There are a couple reasons for this.

1) The purpose of GCM is small payload such as notifications or small data packages. It's not intended for large messages, just small transmissons.

2) GCM makes **no guarantee of delivery.** If you are wanting to chunk a file into these messages and send them then there is a chance that one of them can be lost in transmission since it has no guarantee of message delivery, kind of like UDP. So one lost message and your file is ruined.

Comment: Do you know How happy am I?
Your answer is what i want!
very thanks for your help!

Comment: @ssunghunk I'm glad the answer helped! If it solved your question, please remember to accept the correct answer. =]

Comment: In my recent experience GCM is extremely reliable ... maybe Google has improved its reliability in the 3 years since this answer. You can set up auto read receipts that get sent from the device back to the server once the device has received the message for example. You can also set the time-to-live (TTL) on each message (to 24 hours for example), during which GCM will keep trying to deliver the message to the device.

I'm considering chunking messages which are up to 20kb in size for example, and I will use GCM. Anything over about 5 chunks, yes, I don't think that's an ideal use case.